# getting bad fitting distribution to discrete data

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, fitting, scipy

So I have some sampled data between 0 and 0.2 (the real range is 0 and 0.5) ;and I want to get the distribution of a sampling occurring with a certain value (so approximating the posterior).
I got the count of datas occurring between [a:a+step] with a being in the [0:0.5] interval; wich give me the distribution I want to approximate (I have chosen step=0.01)

[image]

I use the scipy.distrib.fit to try and get the best params for different distributions and keep the best one through sse.

```
import scipy.stats as st

DISTRIBUTIONS = [     
        st.norm,
        st.beta,
        st.pareto,
        st.rayleigh,
        st.gamma
        ]

for distribution in DISTRIBUTIONS:
        print("distrib : ", distribution.name, " start")
        # fit dist to data
        params = distribution.fit(x,y)

        # Separate parts of parameters
        arg = params[:-2]
        loc = params[-2]
        scale = params[-1]
```

I get a beta distribution as best fit with weird parameters values:

```
params = (0.24462444439151423,
 357.45438990039304,
 -8.242680258795525e-25,
 37941.674422085795)
```

Wich indeed gives me a very bad fit :

```
fitted_data = st.beta.pdf(x, params[0],params[1] , params[-2], params[-1])
plt.plot(abcisses_correct,fitted_data,'r-')
```

[image: fitted data]

[image: zoomed fitted data]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any exact 0's in the data? Several of these distributions only have support for positive values, not exact 0's.

Comment: actually when i pass my data i only select the indices which arent zero values with np.nonzero to ensure that

Comment: For the plot at the end, you should also select out 0's. Also your points should be normalized to be a density as well I see. So you should divide the counts by `(counts/total_n)*bin_width`. Otherwise the line and the dots are not on the same scale. 

Pretty sure that 1e17 value is due to the edge condition that should just get an error for the beta distribution.